# How to append only unique values to a key in a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

sorry this is likely a complete noob question, although I'm new to python and am unable to implement any online suggestions such that they actually work. I need decrease the run-time of the code for larger files, so need to reduce the number of iterations i'm doing.

How do I modify the append_value function below to append only UNIQUE values to dict_obj, and remove the need for another series of iterations to do this later on.

EDIT: Sorry, here is an example input/output

Sample Input:

```
6
5 6
0 1
1 4
5 4
1 2
4 0
```

Sample Output:

```
1
4
```

I'm attempting to solve to solve:
http://orac.amt.edu.au/cgi-bin/train/problem.pl?problemid=416

[Output Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHnGr.png)

```
input_file = open("listin.txt", "r")
output_file = open("listout.txt", "w")

ls = []
n = int(input_file.readline())
for i in range(n): 
    a, b = input_file.readline().split()
    ls.append(int(a))
    ls.append(int(b))

def append_value(dict_obj, key, value):          # How to append only UNIQUE values to
    if key in dict_obj:                          # dict_obj?
        if not isinstance(dict_obj[key], list):
            dict_obj[key] = [dict_obj[key]]
        dict_obj[key].append(value)
    else:
        dict_obj[key] = value

mx = []
ls.sort()
Dict = {}
for i in range(len(ls)):
    c = ls.count(ls[i])
    append_value(Dict, int(c), ls[i])
    mx.append(c)

x = max(mx)
lss = []

list_set = set(Dict[x])                     #To remove the need for this
unique_list = (list(list_set))
for x in unique_list:
    lss.append(x)

lsss = sorted(lss)
for i in lsss:
    output_file.write(str(i) + "\n")
    
output_file.close()
input_file.close()
```

Thank you

Comment: Have you considered using a `dict` of `set`s, rather than a `dict` of `list`s?

Comment: Can you provide an example input and your expected output?

Comment: Do you want unique values across the entire dictionary? Or only unique among other elements in a given dictionary value? E.g., can you have `{"a": {1, 2, 3}, "b": {1, 2, 3}}` or no?

Comment: Since your focus is on improving performance, you should note that a single call to `set()` on one sublist in the dictionary is almost certainly **not** the cause of the problem. You're calling `c = ls.count(ls[i])` in a loop over `ls`, the list containing all of your input. *This single line makes the entire program quadratic*. Of course you should profile, but if this is the entire program, I can almost guarantee that line is the sole problem. Use `collections.Counter()` instead

Comment: @ddejohn yes those examples are possible. The Idea is each key is only assigned unique integer values

Comment: @ShadowRanger How do I do that?

Comment: @kcsquared Thank you, could you possible give an example of how to implement that?

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question, 'how to only append unique values to this container' is fairly simple: change it from a `list` to a `set` (as @ShadowRanger suggested in the comments). This isn't really a question about dictionaries, though; you're not appending values to 'dict_obj', only to a list stored in the dictionary.

Since the source you linked to shows this is a training problem for people newer to coding, you should know that changing the lists to sets might be a good idea, but it's not the cause of the performance issues.

The problem boils down to: given a file containing a list of integers, print the most common integer(s). Your current code iterates over the list, and for each index `i`, iterates over the entire list to count matches with `ls[i]` (this is the line `c = ls.count(ls[i])`).

**Some operations are more expensive than others**: calling `count()` is one of the more expensive operations on a Python list. It reads through the *entire* list every time it's called. This is an `O(n)` function, which is inside a length `n` loop, taking `O(n^2)` time. All of the `set()` filtering for non-unique elements takes `O(n)` time total (and is even quite fast in practice). Identifying linear-time functions hidden in loops like this is a frequent theme in optimization, but profiling your code would have identified this.

In general, you'll want to use something like the [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) class in Python's standard library for frequency counting. That kind of defeats the whole point of this training problem, though, which is to encourage you to improve on the brute-force algorithm for finding the most frequent element(s) in a list. One possible way to solve this problem is to read the description of `Counter`, and try to mimic its behavior yourself with a plain Python dictionary.

Comment: Thank you, your explanation on performance was very helpful. I wrote a solution with the counter type - which worked - although as you presumed the submission page does not allow for any imports, so a different solution is required.

Comment: How can I mimimic its behaviour with a plain Python dictionary in such a way that it is a 0(n) function?

Comment: @Checkmate1941 The only relevant behavior needed is the initialization. Starting from an empty dictionary, iterate over your list. If an element x is in your dict, you do dict[x] += 1. Otherwise, you do dict[x] = 1.

Comment: Or alternatively, just do `dict[x] = dict.get(x, 0) + 1`, avoiding the need to test if the key exists yet. In practice, you'd almost always use `collections.Counter` or `collections.defaultdict(int)` for this purpose though. Especially if you can convert your input to one long stream of integers; in that case, `counts = collections.Counter(iterable_of_int)` (possibly followed by `counts.update(another_iterable_of_int)` if you have multiple such streams) will be faster than anything else (`collections.Counter` has a C accelerator for rapidly updating counts for an iterable of things to count).

Comment: Just for funsies, [a mostly idiomatic `Counter` solution](https://tio.run/##fVJLT9wwEL77V4zYA061iqAsHJByQqrUc48tstzE6Y6wx5btpZtfv4ydLAGBmIsfM/4e4wlT3nu6OZ3QBR8zpCkJMUbvoPfWmj6jpwRL8sEfKJs455F32Xv7mu33GmkLmCz2RojBjOD4Rjb3Ajjo4CySSdABUpZkjlkyW5vygNQ0tWaMaGhQQWMsdU4HmXJsU7CYz8jro@0rZtPAhtXRM0uCmSX7BS3tMUBFrBR98VDAFzOyym6LJVUs6b/WyLc6GHuJDfywOmdDKzg4Q3OLNB8q9nrFVf9MPlfWZJXg9FHNpcXiUc6S2mdtDybJle@T2MDPocCPU3mJ7uA@wv9HIlP79zvgAKOPwOsWeiZEWhrQslfHZIBjTXTdKuvxLUyb@G/lk5k6/rWvpL1T@asMxFkI/5KJ2Gtrp4ocYhmAb0t6C8mE7uIPXTRCsBqlSDujVJF0qVQZIaUu75fOlXk6ne7ELdyJK7gW17Dj/Y7X72IHVy8 "Python 3 – Try It Online").

Comment: @ShadowRanger The `get` method is the faster and more idiomatic option; I didn't mention it because it might be unfamiliar to people new to Python (and has less dramatic benefits compared to Counter), although perhaps that's not a good reason. You should consider posting that Counter solution as a separate answer; it's clean enough to be a template for other problems, and probably the most Pythonic way to solve the original problem.

Comment: @kcsquared: I suppose. Leery of solving problems from scratch in completely different ways from the OP's failed attempts, but this was fun and easy to write, so whatevs. [Posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71129890/364696) (and up-voted your answer, which is a good explanations of what's wrong with the OP's existing code, even if they didn't need to do that work in the first place).

Answer (score 1):

Answering the question you haven't asked: Your whole approach is overkill.

1. You don't need to worry about uniqueness; the question prompt guarantees that if you see `2 5`, you'll never see `5 2`, nor a repeat of `2 5`
2. You don't even care who is friends with who, you just care how *many* friends an individual has

So don't even bother making the pairs. Just count how many times each player ID appears *at all*. If you see `2 5`, that means `2` has one more friend, and `5` has one more friend, it doesn't matter who they are friends *with*.

The entire problem can simplify down to a simple exercise in separating the player IDs and counting them all up (because each appearance means one more unique friend), then keeping only the ones with the highest counts.

A fairly idiomatic solution (reading from stdin and writing to stdout; tweaking it to open files is left as an exercise) would be something like:

```python
import sys

from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain, islice

def main():
    numlines = int(next(sys.stdin))
    friend_pairs = map(str.split, islice(sys.stdin, numlines)) # Convert lines to friendship pairs
    counts = Counter(chain.from_iterable(friend_pairs))        # Flatten to friend mentions and count mentions to get friend count
    max_count = max(counts.values())                           # Identify maximum friend count
    winners = [pid for pid, cnt in counts.items() if cnt == max_count]
    winners.sort(key=int)                                      # Sort winners numerically
    print(*winners, sep="\n")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVJLT9wwEL77V4zYA061iqAsHJByQqrUc48tstzE6Y6wx5btpZtfv4ydLAGBmIsfM/4e4wlT3nu6OZ3QBR8zpCkJMUbvoPfWmj6jpwRL8sEfKJs455F32Xv7mu33GmkLmCz2RojBjOD4Rjb3Ajjo4CySSdABUpZkjlkyW5vygNQ0tWaMaGhQQWMsdU4HmXJsU7CYz8jro@0rZtPAhtXRM0uCmSX7BS3tMUBFrBR98VDAFzOyym6LJVUs6b/WyLc6GHuJDfywOmdDKzg4Q3OLNB8q9nrFVf9MPlfWZJXg9FHNpcXiUc6S2mdtDybJle@T2MDPocCPU3mJ7uA@wv9HIlP79zvgAKOPwOsWeiZEWhrQslfHZIBjTXTdKuvxLUyb@G/lk5k6/rWvpL1T@asMxFkI/5KJ2Gtrp4ocYhmAb0t6C8mE7uIPXTRCsBqlSDujVJF0qVQZIaUu75fOlXk6ne7ELdyJK7gW17Dj/Y7X72IHVy8)

Technically, it doesn't even require the use of `islice` nor storing to `numlines` (the line count at the beginning might be useful to low level languages to preallocate an array for results, but for Python, you can just read line by line until you run out), so the first two lines of `main` could simplify to:

```python
next(sys.stdin)
friend_pairs = map(str.split, sys.stdin)
```

But either way, you don't need to uniquify friendships, nor preserve any knowledge of who is friends with whom to figure out who has the most friends, so save yourself some trouble and skip the unnecessary work.

Comment: Thank you, although I already made a solution through importing Counter. The catch is that I need a solution that doesn't use any imports, ie no Counter.

Comment: @Checkmate1941: The use of `Counter` here could be replaced with `counts = {}`, `for pair in map(str.split, sys.stdin): for friend in pair: counts[friend] = counts.get(friend, 0) + 1`, with the rest of the code remaining largely unchanged (removing the use of `chain` and `islice` by the use of nested loops and ignoring the `numlines` respectively).

Comment: Could you please post an example of how to integrate this whilst reading from the input text file, I'm really struggling to make sense of it.

Answer (score -1):

If you intention is to have a list in each value of the dictionary why not iterate the same way you iterated on each key.

```py
if key in dict_obj.keys():
    for elem in dict_obje[key]:  # dict_obje[key] asusming the value is a list
        if (elem == value):
        else:
    # append the value to the desired list
else:
    dic_obj[key] = value
```

Comment: When I try that or anything similar I get the error: "TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable" and am unable resolve it.